# Why do I get the exact same weights for compression levels "None" and "4x" in X-Cube-AI / STM32CubeMX.AI?

Tags: python, c, keras, embedded, artificial-intelligence

I have a Keras model saved in HDF5 (*.h5) format. I'm using the stm32ai command line tool to generate my files nn.c/.h as well as nn_data.c/.h. One example command is the following:

```
~/STM32Cube/Repository/Packs/STMicroelectronics/X-CUBE-AI/5.2.0/Utilities/linux/stm32ai generate --model nn.h5 --verbosity 2 --type keras --name nn --compression 4
```

The nn_data.c file includes the weigths of my neural network. However, when I set compression to 1 which means no compression I get:

```
#include "nn_data.h"

ai_handle ai_nn_data_weights_get(void)
{

  AI_ALIGNED(4)
  static const ai_u8 s_nn_weights[ 3196 ] = {
    0x56, 0xff, 0xa5, 0x3d, 0xb6, 0xa2, 0xf3, 0x3d, 0x18, 0x2c,
    0x4e, 0xbc, 0x69, 0x64, 0xa4, 0x3d, 0x09, 0xf4, 0x27, 0x3e,
...
```

And when I set compression to 4 (4x) I get the exact same weights!

Only for a compression of 8 I get different weights:

```
#include "nn_data.h"

ai_handle ai_nn_data_weights_get(void)
{

  AI_ALIGNED(4)
  static const ai_u8 s_nn_weights[ 728 ] = {
    0x0d, 0x5d, 0xa0, 0xbe, 0x20, 0xf7, 0x86, 0xbe, 0x83, 0xe4,
    0x66, 0xbe, 0xca, 0x73, 0x36, 0xbe, 0x8d, 0xa9, 0xf7, 0xbd,
...
```

We can clearly see that the weight buffer for 8x compression is significantly smaller.

Does someone have an idea why the weights do not differ for the compression levels None and 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In contrast to my expectation the compression does not seem to be always done but only in certain cases which are not completely defined for the public: [See here](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000Bh6BFWSQ2/model-compression-understanding) Additionally, I have looked into the model conversion report nn_generate_report.txt and it does not show a compression mark "(c)" for any of my neural network layers for compression level 4. But for compression level 8 all layers are marked with it. So, I assume that all is fine.